# Как сделать вывод данных из 3 разных таблиц(и 2 общих)?

Tags: веб-программирование

Есть 3 таблицы.
Люди, Отделения и Этаж.
Есть 2 связывающие таблицы.
связь людей и отделений, связь отделений и этажей.
На страницы выводятся 2 блока кнопок, блок с отделениями и этажами.
Я жму на определенное отделение, жму на этаж и мне нужно вывести людей которые соответствуют этому этажу и отделению. Как это реализовать? Делать еще 1 таблицу(хотел бы этого избежать)?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Если есть переменные $floor and $branch:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * 
FROM PEOPLE
LEFT JOIN BRANCH ON B_F.id'
```

Вы можете добавить столько `LEFT JOIN` сколько необходимо.

Comment: Получается запись из PEOPLE с id 1 в P_B соответствует 2 записи из BRANCH. BRANCH с id 2 в B_F соответствует 2 этажам, какой он этаж выберет?